# Find all connected subgraphs of a specified size, not just induced subgraphs, using networkx

Tags: graph, networkx, combinatorics

The subgraph method offered by python's networkx generates induced (full) subgraph given a subset of vertices. I have been unsuccessful in finding a method for delivering all subgraphs (yes, there will be many) of a given graph having a specified number of vertices.

I have been successful in writing code to generate all connected full (induced) subgraphs of a specified size, but want all such connected subgraphs.